# What options to provide for CapacitorSQLite.createSyncTable() when starting to use @capacitor-community/sqlite

Tags: angular, npm, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am watching a tutorial from 2020 about capacitor ionic with sqlite.
(there is not a more recent tutorial unfortunately, anywhere on the internet.)
(https://youtu.be/2kTT3k8ztL8?t=635)

A lot of stuff has changed since then but so far I managed to make all the necessary changes.

Now in the video, this line of code didn't show any errors for the instructor:

```
await CapacitorSQLite.createSyncTable();
```

For me however, it's giving me this error:

```
TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.  definitions.d.ts(180, 21): An argument for 'options' was not provided.
```

Maybe someone knows what I need to change this time?

My import of `CapacitorSQLite` looks like this:

`import {CapacitorSQLite, JsonSQLite} from '@capacitor-community/sqlite';`

#### Additional Info:

This is the block of code I am using it in:

```
  private downloadDatabase(update = false) {
    this.http.get('/assets/db.json')
      .subscribe(async (jsonExport: any) => { // JsonSQLite
        const jsonstring = JSON.stringify(jsonExport);
        const isValid = await CapacitorSQLite.isJsonValid({ jsonstring });

        if (isValid.result) {
          this.dbName = jsonExport.database;
          await Storage.set({ key: DB_NAME_KEY, value: this.dbName });
          await CapacitorSQLite.importFromJson({ jsonstring });
          await Storage.set({ key: DB_SETUP_KEY, value: '1' });

          if (!update) {
            await CapacitorSQLite.createSyncTable();
          } else {
            await CapacitorSQLite.setSyncDate({ syncdate: '' + new Date().getTime() });
          }

          this.dbReady$.next(true);
        }
      });
  }
```

I pinned the exact time in the video where the instructor talks about this in this youtube link:
https://youtu.be/2kTT3k8ztL8?t=635

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure this is correct:

```
 await CapacitorSQLite.createSyncTable({database: this.dbName});
```

I found this when ctrl. + clicking through this method:

```
/**
 * Create a synchronization table
 * @param options: capSQLiteOptions
 * @returns Promise<capSQLiteChanges>
 * @since 2.0.1-1
 */
createSyncTable(options: capSQLiteOptions): Promise<capSQLiteChanges>;


export interface capSQLiteOptions {
    /**
     * The database name
     */
    database?: string;
}
```